# Add an argument that starts with "h"

Tags: python

With this code, I can't seem to add "`--height`" as argument because Python is confused with the "`-h / --help`" default option. I've tried to add `add_help=False` when creating the object but I still get the error `main.py: error: the following arguments are required: height`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my description')
parser.add_argument('height', type=int, nargs=1)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a positional argument. The way argparse works is that when you define an argument without any leading `-` or `--` it will consider it positional, so you have to call the script like `python yourscript.py the_height`.

If you want to call it like `python myscript.py --height 222` then you must do

```
parser.add_argument("--height", action="store")
args_namespace = parser.parse_args()
print(args_namespace.height)
```

Comment: So I should `parser.add_argument('--height'` ?

Comment: Yes; `add_argument` adds both positional and optional arguments, so you have to explicitly provide the `--` to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @OlivierPons yes, you can also use `parser.add_argument('-H', '--height`' in order to to collide with `-h` which is used for help by default.

Comment: @OlivierPons I've updated my answer with an example.